# ASP.NET Web API Async Tasks, sending Mails

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, email, asynchronous

my application has massive performance problems. I found that the problem comes from the sending of emails. How can i fix this problem that the method `RegisterUser` returns, while the sending of the email is still in process? I already tried this with starting a thread to run the `SendEmailConfirm` Method, but that gave me an `ObjectDisposedException` in `SendEmailConfirm`

```cs
public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel userModel)
{
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);
    this.SendEmailConfirm(userModel.Email);

    return result;
}

public async void SendEmailConfirm(string mail)
{

    string subject = "Please confirm your Email for Chronicus";
    string body = "Hello"
    string email = user.Email;

    _messageService.SendMail(mail, subject, body);

}

public void SendMail(string receiver, string subject, string body)
    {
        this._msg = new MailMessage(UserName, receiver);
        this._msg.From = new MailAddress(UserName, Name);
        this._msg.Subject = subject;
        this._msg.Body = body;
        this._msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        this._smtpClient.Send(_msg);
    }
```

EDIT:  Added SendMail method to the question

Comment: What is the signature of `_messageService.SendMail`? is it an async method? what does it return?

Comment: I edited my question and added the method

Comment: 1. Shouldn't you `await` the call to `SendEmailConfirm`? 2. How/when do you `new()` up _messageService? 3. Is `SendMail()` from a different class? Please clarify.

Comment: If `_messageService` is sending mail synchronously, then that's your problem. I'd go back to the implementation of `_messageService` and add an awaitable async method that uses [SmtpClient.SendMailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), thereby allowing the IO to occur properly asynchronously.

Comment: @kayess
1. I understood "await" the way that if I "await" "SendEmailConfirm", the method that calls continues not untill "SendEmailConfirm" was executed. 2. I initialize _messageService in the constructor. 
3. SendMail is in the class MailMessageService. _messageService is an object of this

Comment: @spender I will try this

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [`SendMailAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the `SmtpClient` class.

Also, you should return `Task` for async method that return no value.

Here is how your code would look like:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel userModel)
{
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);
    await this.SendEmailConfirm(userModel.Email);

    return result;
}

public Task SendEmailConfirm(string mail)
{
    string subject = "Please confirm your Email for Chronicus";
    string body = "Hello"
    string email = user.Email;

    return _messageService.SendMail(mail, subject, body);
}
```

And here is how `SendMail` would look like:

```
public Task SendMail(string receiver, string subject, string body)
{
    this._msg = new MailMessage(UserName, receiver);
    this._msg.From = new MailAddress(UserName, Name);
    this._msg.Subject = subject;
    this._msg.Body = body;
    this._msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    return this._smtpClient.SendMailAsync(_msg);
}
```

Comment: `SendMail` doesn't need to be `async`. It can just return `this._smtpClient.SendMailAsync` to save you from creating state machine. Also following the TAP convention, `SendMail` should be renamed to `SendMailAsync`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I updated the answer. I agree with you about the naming convention. I am keeping the method names because I don't want to confuse OP.

Comment: I tried this solution. But "RegisterUser" still waits until the email was sent before it returns the result

Comment: @davidrue, it asynchronously waits. Do you want to fire and forget? How would you handle the case where sending the email throws an exception?

Comment: If you need to fire and forget, then you need to have the message service live beyond the lifetime of the web API request. You can have an single instance of message service that have a singleton lifetime style. Such service should handle errors for you. Such errors cannot be shown in the web request since the request might have been finished before sending the email. But for example it could log the error.

Comment: @YacoubMassad But how can i solve this, when I have a method which sends 20 Emails at its end. With my solution it needs 40 seconds (2 seconds for each email) until it returns the http answer to the client

Comment: If the SMTP sever can handle it, you can send multiple messages at once. You can use `Task.WhenAll` to asynchronously wait for all messages to finish.

Comment: @davidrue If you absolutely don't care about waiting until the emails are done before you send the response, then you can use [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx), or a lot of the technique's listed [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) in Scott Hanselaman's excellent blog post. Otherwise, you can gather all your tasks into a collection and then await on that with `Task.WhenAll` when you need them to complete before returning.